# Pixel array compression

Tags: c++, image-processing, comparison, compression

I am comparing 2 images and getting an array of unmatched pixels like

```
rgb(12, 54, 69) 1 4
rgb(19, 54, 98) 4 8
rgb(12, 54, 69) 2 9
rgb(86, 85, 10) 9 7
```

I need to transmit this over network. so to compress I can make it

```
rgb(12, 54, 69) (1, 4), (2, 9)
rgb(19, 54, 98) (4, 8)
rgb(86, 85, 10) (9, 7)
```

However I doubt this simple compression would not yield much benefit in case of large difference. I'vent run any tests yet.

When the whole image is changed normal JPEG compression of the new image will be much smaller in size. however for any small difference this method will yield a smaller byte overhead. and there is no way to know the amount of change without looping top to bottom of each image.

Is there any standard way of doing the same ? I'll be implementing it in C++ on the top of protobuf or boost serialization and Qt

Comment: I would heavily consider writing your compression algorithm, and run quite a few tests on different image types to see if your compression method truly gives any benefit!  You may find that there are very few instances it does or doesnt provide any benefit.  If it does in most cases, than JUST use your method, else ONLY use jpeg.  This will simplify your comm protocol also as you wont have to add info telling you on the other side how to decompress.  It will also alleviate the need to spend the extra time in size comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Compress the image to jpeg at the start, pass the size of this new jpeg file to your function. As you iterate in your function, as soon as you exceed the size passed in, return a failure and just send the jpeg. This way you do not have to reach the end of your function.

However, I would first profile your current code; In the unlikely case you actually are bottlenecked by this code, you would probably be better served by creating a native/C module for doing this traversal.

Of course this presumes that the time taken by your function exceeds the JPEG creation time on average. As always, profile, profile, profile before optimizing.

Comment: but wouldn't this pixel set be faster jpeg creation ? cause in both ways I still need to compare. cause if they are same I don't send the new image and sit idle for a change.

Comment: @NeelBasu to see if the pixel set creation is faster than JPEG compression *in practice*, you need to profile (i.e. perform experiments and make measurements). You also need to profile your set-based image compression to see if it is actually worth it for most cases like trumpetlicks mentioned in his comment.